# How to realize rotaiton weapon like enter the gungeon?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am creating top down 2d game. I have 8 animation movement character (without hands) in 8 directions. I also have animation weapon (chainsaw) and his animation. In my script I rotate character behind the mouse cursor and I want the weapon to rotate 
around the hands relative to the mouse cursor.

I am from Russia and you maybe don't understand what i want to say (Excuse me), so I will give a way to solve the problem of another person. I try to realize it.

---

I've been thinking about using stumpy armless sprites, each sprite has a walking animation in 8 directions.

I will have a separate image with a hand sprite.

I will draw all my weapon sprites as separate files.

Then I will make the hand sprites follow the player body (as child game objects) - the equipped weapon will be a child game object of the hands.

The weapon will rotate to face the mouse position (unless its a melee weapon - in which case it will just stay stationary) and the hands will be positioned accordingly.

I will need to consider z-order for the weapons and hands, e.g the weapon will always be held in direction the sprite is facing, if the sprite is facing away from the camera then the weapons and hands will need to be drawn before the player.

---

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without code.

If you split the body of your character in two, and have the head on a higher level than the rest of the body, your gun can just rotate around the lower half of the body, without any additional calculations or scripts.

Comment: But weapon should rotate around the hands

Comment: Why do we need to split the body of the character from his head?

Comment: It would allow the gun to be hidden behind the head of the character